# Duda sobre pilas C++

Tags: c++, pilas

Tengo una duda con un ejercicio de pilas, cuyo código es el que tenéis abajo, lo que quiero preguntar es **por qué se desapilan los operandos**, se les hace un pop, antes de operar con ellos? me refiero a esto:

```
const int r_op = stack_.top();
stack_.pop(); // aqui está mi duda, se le hace un pop antes de operar con él?
```

Y otra duda, se supone que para apilar un elemento se tiene que recurrir al push, eso es diferente a hacer esto? `const int r_op = stack_.top();`si me  podríais explicar eso. Gracias

```
void operate(char operador){ //operando derecha,izquierda, lo mete en la pila, cuando terminamos, con pop sacas lo que hay en la pila, Y QUÍ ES DONDE SE OPERA CON ELLOS, SE GUARDA EL 4 EN R_OP, Que ya de por sí está en el top, luego se le elimina, se le hace un pop, y el 3 pasa a ser el top de la pila, se guarda en left_op, y luego se elimina de la pila con pop

    const int r_op = stack_.top(); //añadido, right es el primer elemento en salir en la pila, recuerda el símil de la caja, operamos de izquierda a derecha
    stack_.pop();                   
    const int l_op = stack_.top();
    stack_.pop();

    int result = 0;
    switch (operador) {
        case '+': result = l_op + r_op; break;
        case '-': result = l_op - r_op; break;
        case '*': result = l_op * r_op; break;
        case '/': result = l_op / r_op; break;
        /* ... */                          
    }
    stack_.push(result);   
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Tienes que ser más específicos en tu problema, y evitar comentarios tan largos dentro del código fuente.

Comment: no estoy de acuerdo con lo de los comentarios en su código. Si los usa para aprender no estarían nada mal.

Comment: buen punto @gbianchi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Falta explicar el contexto donde se usa este código pero igualmente deduzco que es parte de un compilador o intérprete y se usa la pila para resolver operaciones aritméticas.
La idea es que cuando se invoca la función/método `void operate()`, en la parte superior de la pila están guardados los dos operandos, por ejemplo 3 abajo y 4 arriba que vinieron de una expresión tal como por ejemplo:

> 3 + 4

Como la idea es resolver la expresión, se deben eliminar los dos operandos de la pila y reemplazarlos por el resultado (7=3+4).
Entiendo que en esta implementación de pila, la primitiva `top()` devuelve el valor que está al tope de la pila pero no lo elimina, y para eso se necesita la primitiva `pop()`. Por último `push(result)` lo que hace es poner el resultado de la operación al tope la pila (en reemplazo de los dos operandos que ya fueron eliminados), es decir lo inverso a `top()` y `pop()`.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque no lo creas tu pregunta es agnóstica del lenguaje que estas usando..

En tu caso, fíjate que esa clase utiliza `top` para ver el primer elemento que esta en la pila, `pop` para sacarlo y `push` para meter un elemento. Entonces, como `pop` en el caso que estas mostrando no devuelve el elemento que sacaste, debes usar primero `top` para ver que hay en la punta de la pila. y `pop` después para sacarlo (porque una pila no se puede recorrer).

Tu segunda pregunta no tiene sentido

```
const int r_op = stack_.top();
```

Hace que guardes lo que esta en la punta de la pila en r_op. con `push` insertas algo en la pila.

**Otra nota**: no se porque defines las variables que sacas de la pila como const. Algún experto seguro podrá explicarte mejor, pero esas no son constantes.